# Replacing values in a df between certain values (replace >1 to 4 with 1)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-loc

I would like to replace certain value-thresholds in a df with another value.
For example all values between 1 and <3.3 should be summarized as 1.
After that all values between >=3.3 and <10 should be summarized as 2 and so on.

I tried it like this:
tndf is my df and tnn the column

```
tndf.loc[(tndf.tnn < 1), 'tnn'] = 0
tndf.loc[((tndf.tnn >= 1) | (tndf.tnn < 3.3)), 'tnn'] = 1
tndf.loc[((tndf.tnn >=3.3) | (tndf.tnn < 10)), 'tnn'] = 2
tndf.loc[((tndf.tnn >=10) | (tndf.tnn < 20)), 'tnn'] = 3
tndf.loc[((tndf.tnn >=20) | (tndf.tnn < 33.3)), 'tnn'] = 4
tndf.loc[((tndf.tnn >=33.3) | (tndf.tnn < 50)), 'tnn'] = 5
tndf.loc[((tndf.tnn >=50) | (tndf.tnn < 100)), 'tnn'] = 6
tndf.loc[(tndf.tnn == 100), 'tnn'] = 7
```

But every value at the end will be summarized as a 6. I think that's why because of the second part of each condition. But I don't know how to tell the program to only look in a specific range (for example from >=3.3 and <10).

Comment: Does that answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68195381/grab-value-from-range-of-values/68195588#68195588?

Comment: Ah, thank you. So, if I am seeing this correctly then I only have to change | to &.

Answer (score 1):

i will use np.where() here is the documentation:
[np.where()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
import numpy as np
tnddf0=np.where((tndf.tnn < 1),0,"tnn")
tnddf1=np.where(((tndf.tnn >= 1) & (tndf.tnn < 3.3)),1,"tnn")
#and so on....
```

Answer (score 1):

To form categories like these use [`pd.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html)

```
pd.cut(df.tnn, [0, 1, 3.3, 10, 20, 33.3, 50, 100], right=False, labels=range(0, 7))
```

Sample output of `pd.cut`

```
         tnn cat
0  76.518227   6
1  44.808386   5
2  46.798994   5
3  70.798699   6
4  67.301112   6
5  13.701745   3
6  47.310570   5
7  74.048936   6
8  37.904632   5
9  38.617358   5
```

---

OR

Use [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html). It is meant exactly for your use-case.

```
conditions = [tndf.tnn < 1, (tndf.tnn >= 1) | (tndf.tnn < 3.3)]
values = [0, 1]
np.select(conditions, values, default="unknown")
```